# Is the conventional usage of Python decorators actually misuse?

Tags: python, python-3.x, static-methods, python-decorators

Broadly there seem to be 2 different ways of understanding and using decorators in Python:

1. *Functional programming*

- **Understanding**. Decorators are slick inline higher-order function applications.
- **Usage**: You may want to use decorators to actually carry out non-trivial operations on the decorated function.

2. *Metadata tagging*

- **Understanding**: Decorators are function metadata tags.
- **Usage**. Use well-known builtin decorators to convey intent of usage but not to carry out non-trivial operations on the decorated function.

All the tutorials about "decorators in theory" assume (1). However, all recommended use cases assume (2).

This disconnect leads to confusion in the case of, for example, the builtin `@staticmethod`. It seems that everyone who uses it does so to tag a method which is already static (for lack of a `self` argument) with an explicit indication to the reader that this is the case. Indeed, the docstring for `staticmethod` stipulates this usage (i.e., usage of type (2)).

However, it turns out that using `@staticmethod` actually does have an important effect (so, usage of type (1)). <s>Namely, it makes the method it decorates *available to instances*. I think this is the opposite of the expected behavior for a static method--if you want your method to be strictly static, then you should *not* use `@staticmethod`!</s> (*This reflects a misunderstanding of Python-specific semantics for the term "static"*)

Is the case of `@staticmethod` an isolated issue? Or are decorators in general misused as metadata tags (2) when in fact they have important <s>undocumented</s> (*this effect is technically documented in `static method`'s docstring, as pointed out by @SuperStormer*) side effects (1)?

(Or, alternatively, do I misunderstand some key aspect of the situation?)

Comment: Doesn't `@staticmethod` fall under category 1? Transforming a method into a static method(which have different semantics) seems like a "non-trivial operation on the decorated function". Of the top of my head, I don't recall any decorators that fall under category 2. However, there are plenty of examples for category 1, such as `@app.route`, `@commands.command`, `@dataclass`, `@functools.total_ordering`, just to name a few.

Comment: Agreed. My point is that the great majority of uses of `@staticmethod` are not consistent with this reality. And the docstring for `staticmethod` doesn't particularly clarify things:
*…
Convert a function to be a static method.
A static method does not receive an implicit first argument.
To declare a static method, use this idiom:
       class C:
           @staticmethod
           def f(arg1, arg2, ...):
               …*

Comment: Casual reading of the above easily leads to the conclusion that you should use the stipulated idiom, by convention, when omitting `self` for a function intended to be called from the class and not the instances.

Comment: Isn't that behavior described on the following line "A static method can be called either on the class (such as C.f()) or on an instance (such as C().f())."? If you want Java-like static methods, you want `@classmethod` instead.

Comment: it's only convention in Python that the first argument of an instance method is called `self`. If I define, inside a class, `def my_method(a, b)`, if I call `some_instance.my_method` it actually expects only 1 argument, which will become `b` - `a` will be the instance. I'm not a Python expert but it seems that decorating with `@staticmethod` prevents this.

Comment: @SuperStormer it sounds like you can make the case that Python decorators really do fall under understanding (1), and usage of type (2) is misuse. I think I'd probably accept that as the accepted answer if elaborated.

Comment: Do you have any other examples for category 2?

Comment: I'm thinking of `classmethod`, `staticmethod`, `property`. From the first words of the 3rd result on Duckduckgo for *python decorator staticmethod*:

*Python @staticmethod decorator is used to label a class method as a static method, which means that it can be called without instantiating the class first.*

That strikes me as bad practice / bad understanding (of type (2)), and suggests that decorators are only a syntactic convenience and I should mostly avoid them in my own code (by opting for explicit function calls when higher-order functions are needed).

Comment: `@classmethod`, `@staticmethod`, and `@property` all fall under category 1. I suspect you may be misunderstanding what they do, and/or you may have a weird idea of what qualifies as a "metadata tag".

Comment: There are very few decorators that *only* convey intent, without affecting behavior. The `typing` module has a few, but other than that, most decorators actually do something important at runtime.

Comment: I too do not understand why you think `staticmethod` falls under category 2.

Comment: @SuperStormer nah, `@classmethod` is nothing like a Java static method, it recieves the class as the first argument, whether called on the class or the instance. Fundamentally, you can't always make a 1-to-1 correspondance with Python class features and Java. `staticmethod` is the closest thing to a Java method, but Python methods just work differently than Java methods.

Comment: I don't think I've ever even seen anyone advocate for only using decorators of category (2). Do you have a reference for this? [PEP 318](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/) does not seem to endorse this perspective...

Comment: Again, I do not claim that any decorators "fall under category (2)"; I am referring to the way they are idiomatically understood by others. See the popular search results for "python decorator staticmethod":

https://www.askpython.com/python/staticmethod-in-python

Comment: My personal knowledge of Python decorators consists of 1 day of reading, so I can't assert anything about them with much certainty.

Comment: What do we do with a question like this? It seems like we figured out what's going on (including my prior confusion), but no one has submitted an answer. It's not a very good question as it turns out.